# free() loop, is triggering a break point and seems to not free the element

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I have been working on an assignment which is pretty much done, and all I need to do is free the the double pointer allocated memory, but with the loop when I go through the loop it triggers a break point and seems to not clear it all I'm not sure whats triggering it.
Context: the Create Data function is basically a function that returns a malloc.

```
int main(void){



int i;
    static STUDENT** records; 
    static float averageTotal[SIZE];
    createData(); 
    records = calloc(3, sizeof(STUDENT*));
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        records[i] = createData();
    }

    menu(records, userinput, &averageTotal[0]); 
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++){


            free(records[c]);


    }
    free(records);


    return 0;

}
STUDENT* createData()
{
    STUDENT* result;
    result = malloc(3*sizeof(STUDENT*));
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: added Menu for Context

```
void menu(STUDENT* records, int user_size, float* averageTotal[]){
    int menuV = 0;
    do{

        int userinput;  
        int i;
        static int counter = 0;
        printf("       **********************************\n");
        printf("       *        MENU                    *\n");
        printf("       *  1. Add Student                *\n");
        printf("       *  2. Display all student records*\n");
        printf("       *  3. Quit                       *\n");
        printf("       **********************************\n");
        scanf_s("%d%*[^\n]", &userinput); '\n' == getchar();
        switch (userinput){
            // switch statement with loops.
        case 1:do
        {
            addStudent(records, &counter, user_size);
            printf("Add another record? 1(y) 2(n)\n");
            scanf_s("%d%*[^\n]", &userinput); '\n' == getchar();
        } while (userinput == 1);
        break;
        case 2:
        do{
            displayStudent(records, user_size);
            printf("Display again? 1(y) 2(n)\n");
            scanf_s("%d%*[^\n]", &userinput); '\n' == getchar();
        } while (userinput == 1);
        break;

        case 3:
            menuV++;
                break;





        }
    } while (menuV == 0);
}
```

Edit: added addStudent Function for Context

```
void addStudent(STUDENT* records[], int* counter, int user_size)

{ // A simple function that lets the user add values to the struct. The counter keeps track and changes the element.
    printf("Student: %d", (*counter+1));
    printf(" of 3\n");
    printf("Enter name:\n");
    fgets(records[*counter]->name, 40, stdin);
    printf("Enter Exam 1 Score: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &records[*counter]->exam1); 
    printf("Enter Exam 2 Score: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &records[*counter]->exam2);
    printf("Name:%s",records[*counter]->name);
    printf("Exam 1:%0.2f\n", records[*counter]->exam1);
    printf("Exam 2:%0.2f\n", records[*counter]->exam2);
    (*counter)++;


}
```

Comment: I would guess that you are doing something invalid to `records` inside `menu`.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I don't think Menu is doing anything wrong but I'll add it in there for context

Comment: Do you ever allocate any actual `STUDENT`s? Your code only shows allocation of pointers. What does `menu` expect?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was told for the assignment to use ** so malloc wouldn't use a continuous block of memory

Comment: Since `menu` just calls other functions, we still can't tell what `records` is supposed to contain.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, added in the other function that actually works with records my bad.

Comment: So now it's obvious. You never actually allocate any `STUDENT`s, yet you act like you did with code like `fgets(records[*counter]->name, 40, stdin);`. Can you point to the line of code that allocates enough space to hold a `STUDENT`? I'll bet you can't. For example, `result = malloc(3*sizeof(STUDENT*))` allocates space for three pointers, but no `STUDENT`s.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz honestly in all the examples, I was given for this section on DM It all started with a array of pointers to the struct, and eventually a pointer pointer

Comment: @Jude All of that is fine, so long as you eventually allocate space to hold the objects. You can use pointers to point to things, but you have to allocate space for the things, not just the pointers. The problem is not that you have arrays of pointers to structures, the problem is that you never allocate space for the structures, so your pointers don't point to what you need them to point to -- the space to hold the structures.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see, i'm not sure where to put this new allocation of `STUDENT` structs, will I then have to also free my student structs and my pointer to the structs?

Comment: If `createData` is supposed to allocate space to hold a single `STUDENT`, it should to that -- `result = malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yea, that was the problem i had `result = malloc(sizeof(STUDENT*));` the problems been fixed thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of things wrong here. You seem to have a weak grasp of pointers and dereference.

This line:

```
static STUDENT** records;
```

Creates a variable that's a pointer to a pointer to a datatype.

Ideally you should change the declaration to something that's idiomatic and easier to understand without thinking. Something like:

```
records = calloc(3, sizeof(*records));
```

In the function CreateData() you're assigning the members of `records` to a pointer to 3 pointers.

This line:

```
result = malloc(3 * sizeof(*STUDENT));
```

Should read:

```
result = malloc(3 * sizeof(STUDENT));
```

. The seconds allocates memory for three times the length of the datatype STUDENT. (What you want).

Moving on --

Here is the declaration/definition of the function `menu`.

```
void menu(STUDENT* records, int user_size, float* averageTotal[])
```

And here's how you've used it in your code:

```
menu(records, userinput, &averageTotal[0]);
```

the first parameter, `records`, was defined as a pointer-to-pointer-to-STUDENT. But the definition of `menu` expects only a pointer-to-STUDENT.

Looking at the rest of the code, it's the definition that's incorrect and not the function call.

Same function:

```
void menu(STUDENT* records, int user_size, float* averageTotal[])
```

`menu` expects a pointer-to-pointer-to-float for its third parameter. But you provided a pointer-to-index in the call here:

```
menu(records, userinput, &averageTotal[0]);
```

Without reading much further, it's clear you need to understand pointers better(or stop typing so fast and understand what you're writing!).

Finally, an actual nit-pick. The function CreateData() should be removed and its use should be replaced by function calls to calloc/malloc() directly.